# Emberjs debugging callstack exceeded

Tags: javascript, debugging, ember.js

How to effectively debug callstack exceeded exceptions or "only happens sometimes and seemingly random exceptions" in Emberjs / js? I developed a bunch of debugging tactics in the past year learning JavaScript but the callstack exceeded one is especially annoying.

### Debugging tactics

- read the Emberjs source. do NOT use the minified Emberjs lib during development, the normal one contains assert statements helping you find errors. Knowing how something works helps A LOT.
- `console.log(this/variable)` Now you can see the details about the object your are using, and see what's available in them.
- place `debugger` statements
- update to the latest emberjs.
- **watch [debugging emberjs](http://vimeo.com/37539737)**
- use jslint while coding, to avoid common pitfalls
- learn from your mistakes and refactor your code so the same type of error does not occur again.
- put `var` before all your variables preventing them to become global and avoid **name collisions** which are very hard to debug.
- learn to analyze the callstack.
- learn to put the Browser debugger in break on error. You can do that by making the break button in the JavaScript console purple.
- use the `ObserveBefore()` in combination with debugger statement to see when a binding get's set so you can get a useful call-stack.
- window.billy to conditional set debugger statements. example

  ```
  someView = Em.View.extend({
    buggyMethod : function(arguments){
         //only if window.billy is set the debugger is activated.
         //usefull when method is used a lot and only fails sometimes.
         if ( window.billy ) { debugger; }
         ..more code..
    })
  })
  ```
- Problems with a View instance? To get a view instance in the console: lookup the id in the dom tree of the view element: `<div id="ember667" class=​"ember-view" >` loopup the view instance in the console with `Em.view.views[found_id]`
- When I run into some error that does not provide any context about why my app crashes I disable more and more pieces of my app until I narrowed down the buggy code.
- Avoid bugs with a proper coding style, style guide, and **good names**.
- Avoid long functions and break them up.
- In handlebar templates to figure out why your stuff does not get printed.

  - {{ log variable }}
  - {{ debugger }}

Comment: If you want to ask and answer your own question that's fine, but please don't post answers inside the question itself. Post 1 answer and 1 question if you want to share like that. You might want to pin the question down a bit too though, "tips" is very broad.

Comment: Agree with @Flexo even if this is a good summary, and pointing to a usefull video. I think this is not the place for this on SO, but on the ember-wiki

Comment: how can i change the question now, so I can answer it myself?